# Requests getting dropped by apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, tibco

We've below code which gets executed during server startup where MessageProcessor's receive method keeps listening to a tibco Bus topic. Problem here is few requests gets dropped and also it's not reproducible. It happens occasionally. Any idea why camel is dropping those requests from Bus ?

```
reg.put("MessageProcessor", new MessageProcessor());
            // Create the context and configure route
            context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    from(
                            "bus://"
                                    + subject
                                    + "?poolSize="
                                    + poolSize
                                    + "&account=busaccount&credentials=buscredentials&policy=buspolicy")
                            .threads(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize),
                                    Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize))
                            .to("bean:MessageProcessor?method=receive(Exchange)");
                }
            });
// Start listening
            context.start();
```

Note : We guessed it that dropping happens when when number of requests > maxPoolSize configured above. Looks like that's not the reason. We've modified `short-running-threads` and `long-running-threads` in Jboss standalone.xml however it's value (200) doesn't match with maxPoolSize (50). Do you think they should be same ?
We want to know why camel is dropping those requests from Bus and fix it.

Comment: @Claus Ibsen Can you please help ?